# Firebase admin database always returns null as spnapshot value

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

Following this [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) I'm always getting `null` for `snapshot.val();`. Why is that?

I'm using `node sdk` for accessing `users` collection on firebase database. I'm sure the collection does exist:

[image: users collection]

Requesting users:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const getUsers = (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

admin.database.enableLogging(true);
const db = admin.database();
const ref = db.ref("users");

ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    const users = snapshot.val();
    console.log('users', users); // always null
    response.json({
      success: true,
      result: users
    });
  });
}
```

Setting up `admin`:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: config.databaseURL
});
```

Node version:

v12.4.0

Here is a log from node:

[image]

Comment: Don't know it is related, but can you try using Promises instead of callbacks? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: Thanks for comment, but no, it can not resolve the problem

Comment: Also, have you double-checked your `config.databaseURL`?

Comment: logs show realtime connection established, and I'm sure it's right database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that I missed the main part related to Firebase `Realtime Databases`. There're two types of them: `Realtime Database` and `Cloud Firestore` (The next generation of the Realtime Database). As I'm using the second one, I need to use appropriate namespace of `firebase-admin`, which should be `firestore` (not `database`, which is for Realtime Database - the first one):

```
const db = admin.firestore();

const userRef = db.collection('users');
userRef.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    const users: any = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      users.push(doc.data());
    });

    response.json({
      success: true,
      users: users
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err);
  });
```